# Sharing buffer between Linux kernel modules causing "Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address XXXXX"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have one kernel module which has declaration as `char arr[100];` and exported it like,
`EXPORT_SYMBOL(arr);`

In second module I am trying to use it as `extern char *arr;` and in read of this module when I try to `snprintf(buffer,100,"%s\n",arr);`

This line gives error like

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address XXXXX"
```

What should be cause for this?

Comment: Are you sure that both modules are loaded and the access is required after loading module with arr? I think better way can be to create function, which will return address of the buffer.

Comment: Yes, first inserted module is with arr[100] and then i trying to read value from second module.

Comment: what is the size of "buffer"?

Comment: Saiyam Doshi, please, show full `Oops` report from kernel. You can do a photo or screenshot. And full sources (or parts working with `arr` and `buffer`) of both modules can be helpful.

Comment: @osgx: My problem solved by taking extern char arr[100]; in second module. Thanks for your time.

Comment: is buffer an valid address??

Comment: Could you please answer your own question for posterity ? It makes perfect sense to answer you own question and accept it as "works for me". This will help community as whole. Please read on [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved by taking `extern char arr[100]`; in second module.